# web service work on local but doesn't work on server (It was working before)

Tags: android, .net, web-services, ksoap

I have an android application calls some web service from my .net project. when I set url to local project works like a charm. but I put same project to cloud without any problem, android can't call web service. what was the diffrence now and before is I did upgrade ksoap 2 2.6.5 and some a bit code..

about ksoap 2. 2.6.5 I changed call function to "androidHttpTransport"

I call about 15 web service all gives me this error >

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT

but same server same database just web service on local works like a charm.

looking for help to understand and solve the problem.

thanks

Comment: Looks like the xml parser is encountering an unescaped string. Similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268895/parsing-invalid-ampersands-with-androids-xmlpullparsers